Define concept where a type is invocable with argument satisfying concept
Given the following concept
template <typename T>
concept HasID = requires(T t) {
  { t.get_id() } -> std::convertible_to<int>;
};

And the following classes
struct A { int get_id() { return 4; } };
struct B { int get_id() { return 5; } };

struct Router {
  template <typename F>
  void with_route(bool is_a, F&& f) {
    if (is_a) {
      f(std::get<A>(routes_));
    } else {
      f(std::get<B>(routes_));
    }
  } 

  std::tuple<A, B> routes_;
};

I'd like to be able to constrain the template type F to indicate that it is a function that accepts an argument that satisfies the concept HasID. Something like
template <typename F>
concept InvocableWithID = requires (F f) {
  { f(/* ??? */) };
};

And trying to add another template type like
template <typename F, typename Arg>
concept InvocableWithID = requires (F f, Arg arg) {
  requires HasID<Arg>;
  { f(arg) };
};

Seems to defeat the purpose since the type of Arg have to be specified at the declaration of the function but we don't know if it'll be A or B. In this example I suppose one could do
template <typename F>
concept InvocableWithID = requires (F f) {
  { f(A{}) };
  { f(B{}) };
};

But this only works if all possible HasID types are known ahead of time which they are not in my case.
